# PHP subclass not calling its parents construct

Tags: php, oop

I have some classes set up as this, where -> means 'extends':

```
DBObject -> Article -> Activity
```

`DBObject` contains a generic `__construct` to easily load my objects from the database (hence `DataBaseObject`).

`Article` overrides this `__construct`, for some specialized constructor behaviour.

`Activity` does not implement any `__construct`, as it can be handled by its superclass' `__construct` (`Article::__construct`).

However, for some reason, if I call

```
$activity = new Activity($args);
```

It ends up in `DBObject::__construct`, and passes Article's one all together. I always thought that calls on a subclass were supposed to travel up the subclass line one class at a time. Am I mistaken in thinking that?

**EDIT**: Here's a code snippet: http://pastebin.com/SXpSNVMm. I removed all non-necessary code. I'm calling it like this:

```
$userId = 60;
$title = "TestTitle";
$contents = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
$date = 1356173771;

echo "creating new activity\n";
$a = new Activity($userId, $title, $contents, $date);
```

Placing echo's in the constructors revealed that `Article::__construct()` was not used and it went right to `DBObject::__construct()`.

**Edit 2**: This is a version that should be working properly: http://ideone.com/VJzdI3 . I'm using PHPUnit for testing. This is the output if i run with PHPUnit:

```
creating new activity 
DBObject constructed called 
QUERY: 60 ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '60' at line 1
```

The latter means it's trying to initialize it using meekrodb; That should only happen if i call `new` on a subclass of DBObject with something other than `null` or an array. However, since Article should override __construct, that one should be called first.

Comment: Show us some code. You're probably extending DBObject instead of Article.

Comment: `$this->fromArray($newInfo)` missing semicolon at the end, are you sure you copied the code you're saying doesn't work? Also this wouldn't work because you're using `$this` in static method. Also if you expect `call_user_func_array('newPost', $args);` to call object's method - it won't. `array($this, 'newPost')` would do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding is correct: with the setup you describe creating a new `Activity` would definitely "defer" to `Article::__construct`. If it does not then your description and the actual code have to differ somewhere. PHP has its more than fair share of bugs, but this is a very simple scenario to attribute the surprising behavior to buggy code.

If you still think there is nothing wrong with the code, please post a working sample on an online codepad like htpp://ideone.com that exhibits the issue.

Comment: I edited my post with additional information. Since i was quite sure my code was correct, i first wanted to check if there was a fundamental flaw in my reasoning.

Comment: @ErikDolor: That code isn't live, please take the time to make it so.

Comment: Alright, let me finish up my breakfast and I'll put the semi-working version online. This is quite an edited version.

Comment: Added a new version where only the minimum amount of other code has been left out.

Comment: @ErikDolor: I moved the code around a bit to get it to run, and [it works as it should](http://ideone.com/O2iHS4).

Comment: Alright, now this is definitely strange. What seemed to fix it for me was a require_once for DBObject, Article and Activity in the PHPUnit file, instead of having the require_once Article in Activity.php. Really strange.